# How to execute a function multiple times based on a lookup table

Tags: r, dataframe, function

I have tried a plethora of options and none of them worked for me, so I hope someone here can help me.

to give some context before I go into the problem:
I have a dataframe (df1) with timestamps. I want to alter these timestamps by adding a certain amount of time. The time that I want to add depends on how long of a break was taken. These breaks are not yet incorporated in the timestamps. Df1 contains let's say 20 rows with timestamps ranging between "2022-09-23 00:00:00" and "2022-09-27 00:00:00". Now let's say a 30 minute break was taken on 2022-09-24 at 13:00. What I want the function to do is to add these 30 minutes to all timestamps that come after 2022-09-24 13:00. Moreover, there were several breaks taken, e.g. 8 breaks. My function should retrieve the timestamp of when a break was taken from df2, and add the duration of the break to all timestamps in df1 that come after the moment the break was taken. It needs to do this for every break that was taken.

I made the following function to do this:

```
break_function <- function(df1, df2, row) {
  indices <- which(df1[,1] > df2[row,1])
  if(length(indices) > 0) {
    df1[indices,1] <-  df1[indices,1] + df2[row,2]
  }
  return(df1)
}
```

Here's some example data:

```
set.seed(123)
#creating df1 (for simplicity reasons it exists of only 1 column)
timestamps <- seq(from = as.POSIXct("2022-09-23 00:00:00"), to = as.POSIXct("2022-09-27 00:00:00"), by = "sec")
random_times <- sort(sample(timestamps, 20))
df1 <- as.data.frame(random_times)

#creating df2
breaks <- sample(0:30,8, replace = TRUE)
difftimes <- as.difftime(breaks, units = "mins")

df2 <- data.frame(date = as.POSIXct(c("2022-09-23 12:50:44",
                      "2022-09-23 23:53:27",
                      "2022-09-24 03:31:37",
                      "2022-09-24 08:32:15",
                      "2022-09-24 15:57:31",
                      "2022-09-25 11:17:22",
                      "2022-09-25 11:44:51",
                      "2022-09-26 12:49:43")),
                  break_duration = difftimes)
```

If I execute my function by specifying which row of df2 to use, it works as expected. However, I just can't seem to find a way to call the function for each row of df2. Is there anybody who can help me out with this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this can be achieved faster/more efficient using a `data.table` rolling join on cumulative breaktimes. I could not control, since desired output is missing from your question.. But see if this suits your needs.

```
library(data.table)
# set df1 and df2 to data.table format
setDT(df1);setDT(df2)
# calculate cumulative break_duration in seconds
df2[, break_cum := 60 * cumsum(as.numeric(break_duration))][]
# perform rolling join, create column with time that should be added to random_times
df1[, addTime := df2[df1, break_cum, roll = Inf, on = .(date = random_times)]][]
#           random_times addTime
# 1: 2022-09-23 08:28:57      NA
# 2: 2022-09-23 12:36:43      NA
# 3: 2022-09-23 16:25:33     660
# 4: 2022-09-23 18:06:00     660
# 5: 2022-09-24 00:55:08    2460
# 6: 2022-09-24 01:01:16    2460
# 7: 2022-09-24 10:27:01    4200
# 8: 2022-09-24 10:35:06    4200
# 9: 2022-09-24 13:14:17    4200
#10: 2022-09-24 16:10:07    4200
#11: 2022-09-24 16:20:54    4200
#12: 2022-09-24 20:43:16    4200
#13: 2022-09-25 02:53:23    4200
#14: 2022-09-25 04:29:01    4200
#15: 2022-09-25 05:47:06    4200
#16: 2022-09-25 14:39:48    7200
#17: 2022-09-25 14:51:57    7200
#18: 2022-09-26 02:32:39    7200
#19: 2022-09-26 05:02:03    7200
#20: 2022-09-26 13:42:58    8640
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this definitely helps a lot. Indeed, I forgot to give a desired output. But this will definitely solve my problem!